# Install Docker on Debian stretch

Tags: linux, docker, debian, devops

I'm on Debian and I was following the guidelines in Docker official tutorial for Ubuntu https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/, point `Install using the repository` but after adding new apt sources entry to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] signed=by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

and trying to call `apt-get update` I got this:

```
# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I added Docker's official GPG key, so according to the tutorial this should not happen. My question is - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that now there is the official documentation covering Debian (and not just Ubuntu) so I think it's a good idea to update the question to put it to the Debian documentation, instead of Ubuntu, so it's less confusing. Here the correct link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/ (mine is a comment, since I tried to edit directly but it was just refused...)

Comment: Hi @robin-daugherty and secretagentman thank you for reviewing my edit. I just want to fix "ubuntu" with "debian" in the original question, but it's not possible now. The question really does not change at all with this fix, but it makes a lot of more sense for both the OP and any other person in the world.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `apt-transport-https` and `ca-certificates` packages first.

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

If this does not help, you have to fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` manually.

Comment: Please at startup add this paragraph to give more context: "Before installing Docker on Debian stretch you first need to add support for the HTTPS download method for apt - that is relatively recent - and also update some known CA certificates."
Thanks! now I cannot edit since the edit queue is full